# Premiere Pro: export individual clips from sequence with all effects applied

Tags: premiere, export, render

I have several long videos that I need to export as individual clips, instead of a completed sequence. The goal is to have a library of clips that a coworker of mine can pull from to make Tik Tok or Instagram videos.

I've tried *Render & Replace* and the Project Manager's *Consolidate & Transcode* option, but neither achieve what I'm after. The exported clips have no color correction, no stabilization, no keyframes, and they don't reflect how they were sized/cropped within the sequence (for example the clips I filmed 16x9 but were cropped in the 9x16 sequence export as their 16x9 originals).

The only real workaround I can think of is to turn each clip into a nested sequence and then select/export those from the Project window. That will become a time consuming process and I'm hoping there's a faster way.

**TL:DR - Is it possible to batch export individual clips from a sequence with the effects, sizing, etc. applied?**

Comment: The nesting method I mentioned does work...and it's as time consuming as I figured it'd be.

Comment: This would be a great feature to include with media management - I'm very surprised it doesn't work with "render and replace". If R&R does work on a nested clip/effect though, there may be a faster spin on your workaround: Could you nest the entire timeline, run 'scene edit detection' on the long nested sequence to recreate your cut points, and then render/replace to get a collection of individual clips with effects applied?